# Module class suffix not allowed in Joomla 4

Tags: module

I'm using some UIkit classes in module suffixes when working with modules. My template added those classes via chrome in Joomla 3.
In Joomla 4 I cannot longer add a Module suffix class like "uk-width-2-3@s" because the filter is not allowing it.

Can this filter be somehow deactivated?

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth asking developers to relax the validation here. It is certainly too strict here. But don't hold your breath. In the meantime, you can remove or change validation using a plugin with `onContentPrepareForm` event.

```
use Joomla\CMS\Form\Form;
use Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin;

class PlgContentExample extends CMSPlugin
{
    public function onContentPrepareForm(Form $form, $data)
    {
        // Check that we are manipulating the correct form.
        if ($form->getName() !== 'com_modules.module')
        {
            return;
        }

        // Remove validation from class field.
        $form->setFieldAttribute('moduleclass_sfx', 'validate', '', 'params');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Of cource we could put the whole CMS upside down with plugins, but thats not practical when doing extensions. There is already an issue on it:
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/37542 
Looks like leading Joomla people don't know escaped @ is valid:
https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters